# Share multiple items on facebook

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I need to build a page with 2 different facebook share instances. 
- there is a video i want the end-user to be able to share on his/her profile. 
- and then, there is the page itself, which i'd like the user to share.

how to build a page that can let users share 2 different items on a single page?

Answer (score 1):

You just need two separate Facebook Like Boxes or Buttons (note that Like Boxes can only reference Facebook Pages), each configured to the relevant URL (either the video or the page). You'll only need the script and fb-root tab once on the page.

- [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) documentation
- [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) documentation

Comment: Man ask about share button, NOT like e.t.c!